# FirstIndex:of: in an array of objects

Tags: arrays, swift

I have this class:

```
class ValueTimestamp {
  let value: Double
  let timestamp : Double
  init(value:Double, timestamp:Double) {
    self.value = value
    self.timestamp = timestamp
  }
}
```

then I have an array of objects of this class.

Now I want to scan that array and find the object of `ValueTimestamp` class with the minimum value.

Suppose the array has 3 elements

1. `element1` (value = 12, timestamp = 2)
2. `element2` (value = 5 , timestamp = 3)
3. `element3` (value = 10, timestamp = 4)

and

```
let myArray = [element1, element2, element3]
```

now I want to find the element that has the minimum value.

I supposed this would work

```
let min = myArray.map({$0.value}).min()
let minIndex = myArray.firstIndex(of: min)
```

but the second line gives me this error

> Incorrect argument label in call (have 'of:', expected 'where:')

any ideas?

Comment: `ValueTimestamp` is a kind of unclear name ("Value" has a lot of different meanings in the Swift world. One is about value vs ref semantics, another is about values vs types, and I'm sure there's more). Might I suggest `TimestampedValue`? Although that's not even a precise name either, because "value" is very general, but this only stores doubles. Perhaps `TimestampedDouble`? Or perhaps you could make it generic: `TimestampedValue<T>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`firstIndex(of: )` does not work because I presume your class does not conform to `Equatable`.

Thats why it is expected from you to use `firstIndex(where:)` for this case.

Also in the code below you are not getting an object, you are getting the value, so `min` is type of `Double?` not `ValueTimeStamp?`:

```
let min = myArray.map({$0.value}).min()
```

You could get the min index with the following with using where:

```
let minIndex = myArray.firstIndex(where: {$0.value == min})
```

References:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2994720-firstindex
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2994722-firstindex

Comment: Xcode is giving me an error saying `Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Double' and '_'` Remember that `value` is Double.

Comment: It works fine for me though, I wonder why it says == cannot be applied to Double and _  `let minIndex = myArray.firstIndex(where: {$0.value == min})` min is here a type of double anyways. Its weird

Comment: no need to map the values you can use max method on the collection indices. `if  let index  = myArray.indices.min(by: { myArray[$0].value < myArray[$1].value }) {
    let minValue = myArray[index]
    print(minValue.value)
}`

Comment: This does 2 passes through the array, which is unnecessary. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 5):

`firstIndex:of:` looks for the first element that is *equal to* the provided argument. But you aren't looking for an element that's equal to it, you're looking for one whose `value` property is equal. So you need to use `where` and provide a function for that instead:

```
let minIndex = myArray.firstIndex(where: {$0.value == min})
```

You could also make your class conform to `Comparable` and call `min` on it directly:

```
class ValueTimestamp: Comparable {
  let value: Double
  let timestamp : Double
  init(value:Double, timestamp:Double) {
    self.value = value
    self.timestamp = timestamp
  }

  static func == (lhs: ValueTimestamp, rhs: ValueTimestamp) -> Bool {
    return lhs.value == rhs.value
  }
  static func < (lhs: ValueTimestamp, rhs: ValueTimestamp) -> Bool {
    return lhs.value < rhs.value
  }
}

let minObject = myArray.min()
```

Note that if it's possible to have two objects with the same `value`, you may need to adjust the functions to determine which one is "less" in that case.

Comment: This implementation encodes that the equality and comparability of `ValueTimestamp` hinges only on `value`, which might not be desirable. Two instances with differing timestamps would be considered equal. That might be intented, or it might not be, but it's worth pointing out.

Comment: @Alexander Yes, I mentioned that at the end.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery Oh, I found that kind of unclear.I understand it now, but for completeness and the sake of others, could you elaborate on it in your answer?

Answer (score 0):

The root cause here is that `firstIndex(of:_)` is only defined on `Collection where Element: Equatable`. Your type isn't equatable, so this method isn't available to you, until you make it conform.

However, your problem can be more elegantly solved by using [`Array.enumerated()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1687832-enumerated) and [`Array.min(by:_)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2298201-min):

If you only need the element, you can do this:

```
 let timestampedValues = [element1, element2, element3]

 let minTimestampedValue = timestampedValues
      .enumerated()
      .min(by: { $0.value })

print(minTimestampedValue as Any)
```

If you only need the index, you can do this:

```
let minTimestampedValueIndex = timestampedValues
            .enumerated()
            .min(by: { $0.element.value < $1.element.value })?.offset

print(minTimestampedValueIndex as Any)
```

If you want both, you can do this:

```
let minTimestampedValuePair = timestampedValues
                .enumerated()
                .min(by: { $0.element.value < $1.element.value })

print(minTimestampedValuePair.offset as Any, minTimestampedValuePair.element as Any)
```

All three of these snippets obtain the answer using only a single pass through the array, which makes them twice as fast as the "find the min, then find its index" approach.

Comment: This gives you the element not the index.

Comment: enumerated gives you the offset, not the index. This would work for an array but not for an slice of it. You should always work with the collection indices. `if let index = myArray.indices.min(by: { myArray[$0].value < myArray[$1].value }) { let minValue = myArray[index] print(minValue.value) }`

Comment: @LeoDabus It depends on what OP is trying to achieve exactly. But if non-zero based indices are desired for slices, the best way to do that is by replacing `array.enumerated()` with `zip(array.indices, array)`

Comment: no need to zip if you have the index you have access to the element as well. Btw it was just a note to clarify that offset it is not the same as index. if you really like that zip stuff `extension Collection {
    func enumeratedIndices(body: ((index: Index, element: Element)) throws -> ()) rethrows {
        try zip(indices, self).forEach(body)
    }
}`

Comment: @LeoDabus "if you have the index you have access to the element as well" In O(1)?

Comment: If you are all concerned about speed you can extend the language as I showed in the comment above using the zip approach or use the standard approach with a basic loop and collection's `formIndex(after:)` method: `extension Collection {
    func enumeratedIndices(body: ((index: Index, element: Element)) throws -> ()) rethrows {
        var index = self.startIndex
        for element in self {
            try body((index,element))
            formIndex(after: &index)
        }
    }
}`